# Is incorrect the Landau's demonstration?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Leon Henkin says, at the end of his On Mathematical Induction text, Edmund Landau (Foundations of Analysis) failed to demonstrate the existence and uniqueness of adding natural numbers, because ignored axioms P1 and P2 of Peano.
My question:
Is even incorrect demonstration by Landau?
I could not see any deficiency.

Below are two links. The first to the work of Landau (See Theorem 4.) The second to the text of Leon Henkin.

http://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/503/foundations-of-analysis.pdf

https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/henkin-mathematical-induction-pdf.62910/

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided the text for us not having it in front of us.

Comment: Henkin's papers seems to be at http://www.jstor.org/stable/2308975.

Comment: The only thing about Landau I can see, reading rapidly, the above paper by Henkin is that he failed *to recognize the significance*, in Kalmár's proof of Theorem II ("In every induction system there' is a unique operation of addition"), the fact that this proof doesn't use axioms P1, P2 of Peano's. Nothing about Landau failing to prove something...